# Group ring of galois group

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $E/F$ is Galois extension. What is it known about structure of $F[Gal(E/F)]$?

I've learned only one fact in this direction - existence of normal basis in $E/F.$ But it's not truly about $F[Gal(E/F)].$

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, is there something nice that can be said about $F[G_{E/F}]$ that doesn't derive from results on group algebras in general? [i.e. something structure-theoretic that distinguishes these group algebras from others]

Comment: @anon: Now I'm reading your answer to the similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/470572/67230 )